# Getting error as part of trying to upgrade Service Fabric Application using Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

We got a Service Fabric cluster in our development environment using 2 VMs. I was trying to upgrade the Application deployed in SF using the following command:

Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName "fabric:/ApplicationName" -ApplicationTypeVersion "3.7.2625.0" -UnMonitoredAuto

I get the following error as a result:

> Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade : Application type and version not found
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName "fabric:/ApplicationName"  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade], FabricElementNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UpgradeApplicationErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartApplicationUpgrade

I would like to know whether there are any configurations I need to change at the ClusterConfiguration level. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 simple steps to upgrade an application:

1. `Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage`
2. `Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType`
3. `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade`

By the message you posted, the error is likely because you missed the step 2.

If you have executed the step 1, 2 and 3, certify that:

- The application package has been registered correctly
- The application version you registered is correct, both match, the package and the Upgrade command
- The existing application and the registered one are from same type

Check this doc for more info: [Service Fabric application upgrade using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial-powershell)

Comment: Thanks . Yes , have missed the 'step 2'.  thought we need to register only if it is a new application type. after that had to set the property EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade as true part of fabricSettings in ClusterConfig. Upgrade worked fine after that.

Comment: `EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade ` is another issue and is not related to the error above. You needed it because your new app manifest is changing default services, if not, you wouldn't need this change.