# Azure Service Fabric publish upgrade from Visual Studio - PowerShell Script Error

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to publish an upgrade of a Service Fabric application from Visual Studio 2017 to our Azure Service Fabric Cluster.  In mid-September, I successfully published an upgrade of this same app with same PowerShell script to SFC with no issues.  I am now trying to upgrade it at the next version number and suddenly getting this error.

I get the following error during Publish, related to Powershell.

```
2>Started executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
2>powershell -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ". 'C:\Users\pj\Source\Workspaces\VDevelopment\trunk\Services\Sources\src\For.Application.ServiceFabric.Sources\Scripts\Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1' -ApplicationPackagePath 'C:\Users\pj\Source\Workspaces\VDevelopment\trunk\Services\Sources\src\For.Application.ServiceFabric.Sources\pkg\Debug' -PublishProfileFile 'C:\Users\pj\Source\Workspaces\VDevelopment\trunk\Services\Sources\src\For.Application.ServiceFabric.Sources\PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml' -DeployOnly:$false -ApplicationParameter:@{} -UnregisterUnusedApplicationVersionsAfterUpgrade $false -OverrideUpgradeBehavior 'None' -OverwriteBehavior 'SameAppTypeAndVersion' -SkipPackageValidation:$false -ErrorAction Stop"
2>Copying application package to image store...
2>Upload to Image Store succeeded
2>Registering application type...
2>Register application type started. Use Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType to query for status.
2>Running Image Builder process ...
2>Application package is registered.
2>Start upgrading application...
2>aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices
2>Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade : aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices
2>At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
2>Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-UpgradedServiceFabricApplication.ps1:317 char:13
2>+             Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade @UpgradeParameters
2>+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Start-ServiceFa 
2>   bricApplicationUpgrade], FabricException
2>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UpgradeApplicationErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.StartApplicationUpgrade
2> 
2>Finished executing script 'Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1'.
2>Time elapsed: 00:07:39.0407526
2>The PowerShell script failed to execute.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Again, when I last published this in September, with the same script, no issues at all, and I haven't made any changes to the solution other than upgrading the Manifest versions to push it out as a new upgraded version.

I noted this S/O thread: [Getting error as part of trying to upgrade Service Fabric Application using Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768831/getting-error-as-part-of-trying-to-upgrade-service-fabric-application-using-star) and saw the user's error was similar, but the answer does not apply to my issue because all three steps in the answer provided are definitely included in my powershell deploy script.

I can add the deployment script if helpful, but will wait until that is requested as it's long, and I only want to post it here if someone feels it's needed to diagnose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are changing some parameters in a DefaultService that are not allowed by default.

The link [aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices](http://aka.ms/upgrade-defaultservices) shown in the error logs explain this.

> **Some** default service parameters defined in the application manifest
> can also be upgraded as part of an application upgrade.
>
> Only the service parameters that support being changed through
> Update-ServiceFabricService can be changed as part of an upgrade. The
> behavior of changing default services during application upgrade is as
> follows:
>
> 1. Default services in the new application manifest that do not already exist in the cluster are created.
> 2. Default services that exist in both the previous and new application manifests are updated. The parameters of the default
>    service in the new application manifest overwrite the parameters of
>    the existing service. The application upgrade will rollback
>    automatically if updating a default service fails.
> 3. Default services that do not exist in the new application manifest are deleted if they exist in the cluster. Note that deleting a default
>    service will result in deleting all that service's state and cannot be
>    undone.

Also, there is this other SO question about the same thing: [Default service descriptions can not be modified as part of upgrade set EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798976/default-service-descriptions-can-not-be-modified-as-part-of-upgrade-set-enablede)

The item 1 above is a common approach, where new services are added to the solution and later created during the upgrade without errors, the item 2 and 3 are the restricted approach that requires the `EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade`.

The item 2, is like described in the answer you've added, you changed `MinReplicaSize` and `TargetReplicaSize` to 1 during a manual update, when SF validated the state of your service for upgrade, it identified the difference and prevented the upgrade to continue, if you had set cluster setting `EnableDefaultServicesUpgrade` to `true` it would continue and override the default values.

The item 3, would occur you when you removed the service and added again, you had changed or misspelled the name, SF default settings would prevent the deletion of this service.

Regarding the solution you've found(delete and recreate), is not ideal,
In scenarios where you have stateful services running in production, would be risky to apply, because you would have to backup the state, re-deploy the services, and restore the backup, in some cases, depending on what these changes are, you wouldn't be able to restore the backup, because they have to match with the original services definitions (partitions type, number, and son on). You would also lose the benefits of Rolling Updates, and your service would go down maybe for a while if these backups are big.

Comment: Hi again Diego - I am just going to start calling you the Service Fabric Expert around here.  I figured out the problem:  Please see my answer.

Comment: lol, I am far from being an expert, SF is too complex to know everything, I hang around here to learn from other questions, when I know the answer I do my best to help!

Comment: Regarding your answer, the problem is technically what I said above, TargetReplicasizes are one of the values restricted to change by default, changing outside a deployment make it aligned with the update parameters and avoid the issue.

Comment: Diego - I understand - I think my answer is helpful too though as it can help a reader understand that if they made any manual changes inside SF Explorer, it could cause issues with the next deployment - and my issue was related to a nodes mismatch as I discovered through research.  In any case, I would be happy to mark your question as the answer if you wanted to somehow work some of my detail into your answer (example, perhaps add to your answer "as OP mentions in his answer the issue was caused by...... which is one of the restricted values), or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with us trying to push out the application with mismatched node instances.  We have a stateful service running under this application that is supposed to have MinReplicaSize and TargetReplicaSize set to 3. Yesterday, due to an issue, we deleted and re-created this service inside the SF Explorer. Upon doing so, it reset the replica size parameters back to 1. So we used a Powershell script to change them back to 3, but that script did not include all the necessary commands to get the service back to the exact state it was in before we deleted it.  So today when we went to upgrade the app, the app in SFC wouldn't accept an upgrade from VS deployment, because of mismatches between what was in the parameters of the solution vs. what was in our SFC. To resolve, we re-deleted those services first, then deployed from VS, and no more error.

Comment: Have you tried to update replica counts using [Update-ServiceFabricService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/update-servicefabricservice?view=azureservicefabricps) cmdlet and then perform the upgrade again?

Comment: @OlegKarasik Update-ServiceFabricService is exactly what I used to change the replica size parameters.  Based on Diego's answer, the problem really started when we deleted the service to begin with, because it was a Stateful service.  At that point, trying to add the service back via Explorer instead of a re-deploy from source code was futile.